# how to call an external jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/skhare/myFirstStyleSheet.css">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>

        <script>
                function myFunction(a)
                {
                    window.alert("hi " + a);
                    $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/tableList.json', function(tableList) {
                        var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
                        output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "Table Names" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
                        for (var i in tableList.t)
                        {
                            output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=/Users/skhare/tableDescription.html>" + tableList.t[i].name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                        }

                        output+="</table>";
                        document.getElementById("placeholder1").innerHTML=output;
                    });
                }
        </script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/reportSuiteList.json', function(reportSuiteList) {
              var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
              output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "id" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "name" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "stage" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "DWH" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
              for (var i in reportSuiteList.suites)
              {
                output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_ID + "</td>" + "<td>" + 
                "<button class=\"report-suites\" id =\""+ reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME+ "\" onclick= \"myFunction(\'" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME + "\')\">"+reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME + "</button>" +
                "</td>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].STAGING_DATABASE + "</td>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].DWH_DATABASE + "</td>" + "</tr>";
              }

              output+="</table>";
              document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
            });
          });
          </script>
      </head>

      <body>
          <div id="placeholder"></div>
          <br><br><br>
          <div id="placeholder1"></div>

      </body>
      </html>
```

I want to call myfunction(a) on click of button. I tried as above but myfunction() only displays the alert message. One option is to place the 
script in myFunction(a) in anothe html file and call the file onclick of button but i do not know how to do it.
Please help

Comment: `<script src="yourfile"></script>` on the head tag

Answer (score 2):

To create your own script, open notepad and put all the JavaScript contents, (do not use `<script></script>` here) and save it as `myscript.js`.

In your HTML File, include it as:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="myscript.js"> </script>
```

Make sure you are including it after loading jQuery.

And in your `myscript.js`, to be perfect, put all the code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // All your code here...
});
```

From your question, the `myscript.js` contents should be **only** the following:

```
function myFunction(a)
{
  window.alert("hi " + a);
  $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/tableList.json', function(tableList) {
    var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
    output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "Table Names" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
    for (var i in tableList.t)
    {
      output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=/Users/skhare/tableDescription.html>" + tableList.t[i].name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    }

    output+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder1").innerHTML=output;
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/reportSuiteList.json', function(reportSuiteList) {
    var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
    output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "id" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "name" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "stage" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "DWH" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
    for (var i in reportSuiteList.suites)
    {
      output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_ID + "</td>" + "<td>" + 
        "<button class=\"report-suites\" id =\""+ reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME+ "\" onclick= \"myFunction(\'" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME + "\')\">"+reportSuiteList.suites[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME + "</button>" +
        "</td>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].STAGING_DATABASE + "</td>" + "<td>" + reportSuiteList.suites[i].DWH_DATABASE + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    }

    output+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
  });
});
```